# Does GHC use dynamic dispatch with existential types?

Tags: haskell, existential-type, dynamic-dispatch

Does the following bit of code use dynamic dispatch as it's understood in C++ or Java?

As I understand, at the last line, compiler cannot possibly know at compile time which implementation of (==) to call, yet the code compiles and produces correct results.
Can someone please explain, what kind of implementation (vptr, for example) lies behind this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Value = A Int

data ForallFunc = forall a. Eq a => Forall (Value -> a) 

unpackA (A int) = int

equalityTest :: Value -> Value -> ForallFunc -> Bool            
equalityTest arg1 arg2 (Forall unpacker) =
  let a1 = unpacker arg1
      a2 = unpacker arg2 in
    a1 == a2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roughly, yes.

When you use a *bounded* existential quantification, i.e. when the quantified type variable is restricted by some constraint `C a => ...` then GHC will store some pointer(s) inside the constructor, remembering the methods of `C a` so that they can be accessed later on, when you pattern match on that constructor.

Usually a single pointer is used, much like a `vptr` to a `vtable` in many OOP implementations. The compiler could also instead store the pointers to the methods directly, avoiding the indirection. I think this is done by GHC when there's only one method in the type class. It might also be used when there are very few, say two, methods -- this would make the memory footprint of each value larger, but faster to access.

So, compiling your code is rouhgly done as if the constraint is replaced with an `Eq` dictionary, listing its methods. That is:

```
data EqDict a = EqDict
   { eq  :: a->a->Bool
   , neq :: a->a->Bool }

data ForallFunc = forall a. Forall (EqDict a) (Value -> a) 

unpackA (A int) = int

equalityTest :: Value -> Value -> ForallFunc -> Bool            
equalityTest arg1 arg2 (Forall eqDict unpacker) =
  let a1 = unpacker arg1
      a2 = unpacker arg2 in
    eq eqDict a1 a2
```

Of course, compiling a constructor call `Forall someFunction` is compiled, roughly, by providing the implementation for the needed `==`, `/=` functions, on their specific type which will be abstracted away by the existential quantification.

Comment: Is there maybe some link to an article or a blogpost on this matter you could provide?

Comment: @richie I can't find anything, sorry. What I wrote comes from folk lore. You should be able to find material on the dictionary-based implementation of type classes, by googling a bit. Seeing how dependently typed languages (Coq, Idris, Agda) work with existential types also helps: there, the type argument is (by default) explicit, instead of implicit like in Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, ghc uses a form of dynamic dispatch. The `Eq a` constraint means that the representation for `ForallFunc` will contain a dictionary (corresponds to a vtable) which is used at runtime to call the right equality function.